# Apply ColorStateList to view programmatically

Tags: android, background-color

I have a ColorStateList to apply it into my ListView, but the question is how to apply it to my View? I tried setBackgroundColor() or setBackground() but it was error. So how to apply it?

Here is my code

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {new int[] { }, new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected}};
int[] colors = new int[] {Color.BLACK, Color.RED};
ColorStateList myColorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

Comment: `View#setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList tint)` or `TextView#setTextColor(ColorStateList colors)` or `GradientDrawable#setColor(ColorStateList colorStateList)` for example

Comment: and of course it depends on what you want to use your `ColorStateList ` for

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work in my case
I don't know.. I just want to make background color listview into custom.
So I added that code into adapter but not working.

Right now I tried to use listselector but still searching for set listselector programmatically

Comment: then simply use `StateListDrawable`, not `ColorStateList`

Comment: nice.. thanks for your tips!